# Unwanted Circular plotted Nodes

Tags: python, random, graph, coordinates, networkx

I am trying to generate random Graphs, for that i create a list of Nodes with random X and Y coordinates

My Problem is that these Nodes seem to always align in a circle and i want them to be placed random in a square shaped area without a big empty space in the middle. I have tried to use random.random() and random.gauss() and other random.normalvariate(), but i always get a similar result. Do i have to use another random function to achieve this or is there a mistake how i assign the random coordinates?
here are some example plots

[image: Plot #1][image: Plot #2]

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import string

alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

c=3
r=10
Array = [[0] * c for i in range(r)]

#Fill array with random Coordinates and a Name
for n in range(len(Array) - 1):
    Array[n][0] = alphabet.pop(0)
    Array[n][1] = random.random()
    Array[n][2] = random.random()
G = nx.Graph()

# Add Nodes To Graph
for [name, x, y] in Array:
    G.add_node(name, pos=(x, y))

#Plot it
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=200)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add change `nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=200)` to `nx.draw(G,pos=G.nodes('pos'), with_labels=True, node_size=200)`.